# How to determine when an Azure App Service (or Plan) underlying Node is changed

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to determine in the portal when each time an App Service (plan) is degraded or shifted to a new node.  The Server Names change from something like RDXXXXXX to something else but I'd assume this is logged somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine this  in our local environment, we have created an sample web app (running with .Net(6.0)framework on windows operating system) &  added application insights to the web app to monitor those requests.

You can use live metrics widget , to know the Number of current server name which are up & running ,which are serving the request as shown below.

[image]

Even when you scale out the number of instance in the app service plan using Performance widget  you get what all the new instance were created & how much amount of CPU, requests are serving by them over period of time.

[image]

By writing some kql queries , you can pull the count of requests that each instance was served over a period of time.

```
requests
| where timestamp >=ago(45min)|summarize count() by cloud_RoleInstance
```

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised this info isn't readily available without having to install application insights.

Comment: @lucuma , As per my understanding you need to have application insights in order to record this telemetry

Comment: @lucuma ,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: More importantly, why is there not a default alert when servers are retired? This is not normal outside of a scaling event.